# Spacing of numbers and operators (style)

Tags: formatting, siunitx

This is not strictly a (La)TeX-question, but one regarding stylistic conventions. I wonder if there are any rules regarding the spacing of numbers and operators in normal text. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
(1) \dots bei denen überdies die FFR im Bereich \mbox{$\leq 0.80$} lag~\dots

(2) Darin werden \dots\ ein BMI \SI{< 25}{\kilogram\per\metre\squared}, \dots
\end{document}
```

In the first line, I wrote the term in mathmode, while in the second line `siunitx` did the formatting. You will note that there is some white space between operator and number in the first case and none in the second.

Are there any guidelines or conventions that define what is "good style" for putting something like "less than X", "less than or equal to Y" etc. in text? My gut feeling is that it's wrong to insert whitespace in one place and omitting it in the other -- but what is right? Have I been wrong in using mathmode, or is it a bug in `siunitx` that it doesn't insert white space?

Conventions may differ between countries (e.g., figures up to nine are written as words in English while it's figures up to twelve in German), so I'd be glad to learn about the correct usage of numbers + operators in different languages.

Comment: While I don't know what is proper, one can get the space in the `\SI` version with `\SI{25}[<\,]{\kilogram\per\metre\squared}`, using the `<`  as a pre-unit.  And while I don't know the `\SI` conventions, I would think placing the `<` with the `25` as you show violates the spirit, if not the letter of the `siunitx` approach.

Comment: `\SI` has the format `\SI[<options>]{<number>}[<pre-unit>]{<unit>}`, so you should write the `<` before that command. The pre-unit can be used for a currency sign like $.

Comment: Please don't abuse the pre-unit: that's not semantically the same at all!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes @dexteritas Thanks, that did work, so the stuff formatted by `sinuitx` looked just like that formatted by my own macros. However, in response to Joseph Wright's answer, I finally decided to replace/rewrite my macros so they make use of the semantically correct formatting of `siunitx`.

Answer (score 6):

The logic used by `siunitx` is that when a comparator is given *as part of the number* it is not being used as a relation symbol. As such, the spacing should be different from the case where it is. Thus

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

$\SI{10}{\metre} < \SI{20}{\metre}$ is a comparison, but saying
that we only accept vehicles of length \SI{<7}{\metre} is not.

\end{document}
```

Comment: One could quibble about whether `vehicles of length \SI{<7}{\metre}` actually constitutes a relational comparison between "length" and "7m".  Just sayin'

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for your answer! (I'm sorry it took me so long to reply, but shortly after I posted my question my dad had been hospitalized, so my priorities changed.) Your approach to differentiate between numbers/numbers + units in plain text and  in formulas makes sense, so I changed my own macros to make use of `siunitx`.  
While your answer helped me to complete the work at hand in a satisfactory way, I'm still not sure: Are there any "respectable" guidelines you relied on? As Steven B. Segletes pointed out, there is room for interpretation of semantics, after all.